# How correctly fetch and save data inside an array using useEffect

Tags: reactjs, fetch, mapping, use-effect

I am using React and asynchronously fetching data from the blockchain with useEffect.
What I do not understand is that while the console.log inside the map function works and it prints the right data, supposedly it should save that data inside data array, but when I log data outside the map (meaning it should have finished to save the data) I get an array of undefined values.
Code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const data = mainnet.Vaults.map((pool) => {
      const loadLendingData = async () => {
        const dataPool = await getPoolInfo(pool);
        console.log('dataPool', dataPool) //all good it prints everything
        return dataPool
      };
      loadLendingData();
     })
     console.log('data', data) //[undefined, undefined, undefined and so on]  
     setData(data)
  }, []);
```

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I fixed the problem by storing data with useState for each loop in map.
Code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    mainnet.Vaults.map((pool) => {
      const loadLendingData = async () => {
        const dataPool = await getPoolInfo(pool);
        setLendingData((prevPool) => [...prevPool, dataPool])
      };
      loadLendingData();
     })
  }, []);
```

But still I'd like to understand why the first example didn't work.

Comment: Your map callback doesn't return anything. Also the process is asynchronous, so the resulting values wouldn't be available at that point anyway.

Comment: You are right I completely missed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are not returning anything from the map function, that's why the array has undefined elements outside the map function.

```
return loadLendingData()
```

This should solve the problem for you.